# How to remove the title block from the mobile version in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

Here is the image for an overview
[image]

I want to remove the yellow portion with the title means the total block but there is a problem I **can't inspect element** as that is a static page and I have used **wptouch** to redirect to the custom mobile version website and only customized for **mobile version**, not tablet or desktop and the page is made using **elementor** so please provide any solution for this to solve the problem for the mobile version created page using *elementor*.

Answer (score 0):

you can use wp_is_mobile() function to check for mobile device if it’s a static page.

Comment: no i want to remove the block but i am using elementor so i am not getting the raw html so need help

Comment: Have you tried this:                                     Here's how to responsively hide elements in Elementor:
1. Select the element or row you want to hide.
2. Click the Advanced tab in the editor.
3. Click the Responsive dropdown to open it.
4. Choose whether to hide on Desktop, Tablet or Mobile.